# Trying to get a list of names on a site between "<span class='s-name'></span>

Tags: curl, awk, grep, cat

`cat file | grep "<span class='s-name'>" | awk '/"<span class='s-name'>"/ &&  /</span>`

something about this seems wrong. I mean, other than it's not working.

I also want to put it into a file which I'm pretty sure is just 'filename' at the end.

Comment: Are there nested `span`s in your file?

Comment: yes, one line looks like this
`<div class='signer'>
              <span class='s-name'>Bob Lepine</span>
              <span class='s-title'>Vice President of Content, FamilyLife</span>
            </div>`

Comment: I'm hoping to scrap the titles, all I care about is the name, unless I can get both in a CSV format.

Answer (score 0):

Using **GNU** `grep`

***Input***

```
$ cat infile
<div class='signer'> <span class='s-name'>Bob Lepine</span> <span class='s-title'>Vice President of Content, FamilyLife</span> </div>
```

***Output***

```
$ grep -Po "(?<=<span class='s-name'>).*?(?=</span>)" infile
Bob Lepine

$ grep -Po "(?<=<span class='s-title'>).*?(?=</span>)" infile
Vice President of Content, FamilyLife
```

Answer (score 0):

Using xml/html parsers is the proper way to parse xml/html content, [**xmlstarlet**](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html) solution:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//span[@class='s-name']" yourfile
```

The output:

```
Bob Lepine
```